# Many to many relationship with additional foreign key that has constraint

Tags: sql, database, database-design, foreign-keys

i have this database design

```
Installations
_______________
id

Groups (relation 1:n with installations)
_______________________________________
id
installation_id 

Services (relation 1:n with installations)
________
id
installation_id

Buttons (relation 1:n with services)
___________________________________
id
service_id

buttons_enabled
_______________
group_id
button_id
service_id
```

Actually i have simplified because in fact there is a M:M relationship between services and installations.

What I would like is to constraint buttons_enabled to have button only from a services that is related to installations of that groups.

So for example

Installation
Inst1 
Inst2

Groups
G1 Inst1
G2 Inst11

Services
S1 Inst1
S2 Inst1
S3 Inst2

Buttons
B1 S1
 
B2 S1
B3 S2
B4 S3

Buttons_enabled
G1 B1
 
**G1 B4**

Last row is physically correct but not logical beacuse relate one group of an installation with one services of another installations (B4 is related to Service3 that is related to **Inst2**. But G1 is related with **Inst1**).

How can avoid it?

Thanks

Comment: I dont think you can do it  by fk only, looks like you need insert/update trigger.

Comment: Add the relevant installation to the tables whose rows have associated installations & have composite FKs including installation.

Comment: Perhaps you could append a normal language description of the entities and their relationship with each other. Describe the real objects, not the tables.